perpendicular residuals with scipy odr
I want to fit data to a power-law using scipy odr, which aims to minimize the perpendicular squared distances. I want to find the perpendicular distance between each point and the fit.
The ".delta" returns the |y_model - y_data| residual (vertical distances) for each point and I can't seem to find any built-in method that returns the perpendicular distances. I am sure that they are calculated internally in the algorithm, because they are used to calculate the parameters of the fit, but I am not able to find them anywhere.
If there is indeed no way to get them with one command, how can I do this manually? I can do it if the fitted curve is a straight line, but it is a power-law, and I don't know what to do.

Does this answer your question? Distance between a point and a curve in python

Unfortunately it seems the ODR solution object does not holds any residuals (distances). That would be an interesting feature request anyway.

Lets say you have the following model:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import odr
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

def model(B, x):
    return B[2] * x ** 2 + B[1] * x + B[0]

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
y = model([0.1, 0.2, 1.], x)
sx = 0.1 * np.ones_like(x)
sy = 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)
x += sx * np.random.normal(size=x.size)
y += sy * np.random.normal(size=x.size)

regressor = odr.Model(model)
data = odr.RealData(x, y, sx=sx, sy=sy)
solver = odr.ODR(data, regressor, beta0=[1., 1., 1.])
solution = solver.run()

Inspecting the solution object reveals no residuals (distances).
Then we can use shapely to finish the job.
First we resample and estimate the model (with a bit of extrapolation):
xlin = np.linspace(-0.2, 1.1, 200)
ylin = model(solution.beta, xlin)

We construct a LineString from the interpolation:
fit = LineString([(x, y) for x, y in zip(xlin, ylin)])

Now we can easily compute distance from this curve:
distances = np.array([
    fit.distance(Point(x, y))
    for x, y in zip(x, y)
])

Or even better locate point projections on the curve:
projected = [
    fit.interpolate(fit.project(Point(x, y)))
    for x, y in zip(x, y)
]
projected = np.array([[p.x, p.y] for p in projected])

Graphically it renders as:

